# Hadoop eclipse plugin error

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

I installed Eclipse Luna on VMware Fusion Centos. I tried to run MapReduce hadoop, but I got plugin error. The following plugin doesn't work on eclipse luna. But I already installed jar plugin from here: https://github.com/winghc/hadoop2x-eclipse-plugin
Could someone give me some ideas what's going on here? Should I use eclipse Keplar instead of Luna?

Thanks

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;  
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;  
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;  
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;  
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;    
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
```

Comment: What error you are getting?? Could you please show the error ??

Answer (score 0):

Try running eclipse kepler instead of luna. The hadoop eclipse-plugin may not be compatible for this version of eclipse.